Questions about bands measured by ARPES
Why is there no band gap in the experimentally measured band(in A), contrary to the model's prediction? And in the experimental data, the intensity at the upper left and lower right of the band tends to be stronger than the intensity at the upper right and lower left. Why is that? Is there a fundamental cause?


Could you provide the source of this picture?

Here , https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1130681#body-ref-REF7-1
